# How to change Database file location with EntitiyFramework CodeFirst auto migration and LocalDB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, code-first, localdb

I use localdb in my wpf project app which use entity framework code first. When application running in first time local db database files are created to 'C:\Users\CurrentUserName' path as default. How to change this default path to another location which user selected.

My connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="L10CompanyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=L10Company;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its as easy as this

```
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\path\to\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

[AttachDBFilename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets a string that contains the name of the primary data file.
>   This includes the full path name of an attachable database.

---

[SqlLocalDB Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility)

> Use the SqlLocalDB utility to create an instance of Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2016 ExpressLocalDB. The SqlLocalDB utility (SqlLocalDB.exe) is
>   a simple command line tool to enable users and developers to create
>   and manage an instance of SQL Server ExpressLocalDB. For information
>   about how to use LocalDB

**Syntax**

```
SqlLocalDB.exe   
{  
      [ create   | c ] \<instance-name>  \<instance-version> [-s ]  
    | [ delete   | d ] \<instance-name>  
    | [ start    | s ] \<instance-name>  
    | [ stop     | p ] \<instance-name>  [ -i ] [ -k ]  
    | [ share    | h ] [" <user_SID> " | " <user_account> " ] " \<private-name> " " \<shared-name> "  
    | [ unshare  | u ] " \<shared-name> "  
    | [ info     | i ] \<instance-name>  
    | [ versions | v ]  
    | [ trace    | t ] [ on | off ]  
    | [ help     | -? ]  
}
```

The following example creates an instance of SQL Server ExpressLocalDB named DEPARTMENT using the SQL Server 2017 binaries and starts the instance.

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create "DEPARTMENT" 12.0 -s
```

Comment: I dont have any database to attach because database auto generated by code first migration.

Comment: I have already try AttachDBFilename but get error like that "Cannot Attach the file 'C:\L10_DB\L10Company.mdf' as database 'L10Company'. "